# Prevent Kops from replacing docker installation when provisioning nodes

Tags: docker, kubernetes, amazon-ami, kops, nvidia-docker

I use custom images (AMIs) configured for machine learning on GPU-enabled EC2 instances.

This means `cuda`, `libcudnn6`, `nvidia-docker` etc are all properly setup on them.

**However when Kops starts new nodes from these AMIs (I use cluster-autoscaler) it overrides my properly setup docker.**

**How can I prevent that?**

For now I run a custom script on startup that re-installs `nvidia-docker` properly, but that's obviously not ideal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kops will only install docker if there's a difference between the version it expects to use and the version that is already installed on the node.

Note that Kops will **downgrade** docker [if the installed version is higher than what it expects](https://github.com/kubernetes/kops/issues/908)!

So the solution to my problem was to have a pre-installed version that matches `spec.docker.version`.

For this we had to downgrade docker to `17.03.2` and nvidia-docker to `2.0.3+docker17.03.2-1`.